# What's the best way to fix skirting board without nails / screws?

Tags: drywall, wood, trim

I need to put some skirting board up which will be fixed to some skimmed, dot-and-dabbed plasterboard.

I need to fix it without nails / screws however, as it's in a basement/cellar conversion, and there is waterproof membrane behind the plasterboard which I can not puncture.

I'm planning on using No More Nails / Gripfill, but have struggled getting it flush in the past without putting some pins in until it goes off.

One useful thing is it is in a narrow hallway (about 1.2m) so I'm wondering if I can get away with "wedging" the skirting with 1.2m pieces of stud across the hallway until the glue goes off.

Is there a more elegant solution than this? (Am also worried in case the no more nails gives way at a later date!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could form the skirting directly out of plaster, but that would only fulfill the "appearance" and not the "function" (such as it is) of the skirting board. And for most of us that would be more "messy" than "elegant", though the real plaster pros can do very elegant things in the high side of the wall for moldings that won't see the abuse a skirting board will.

Wedging **is** probably the best way to do this - rather than tryng to get "precise" lengths across, if you can get a pack of tapered shims (narrow wooden shingles) you can use a pair in opposite directions to make a wedge-clamp arrangement on studs just a hair shorter than the width. Drive in the wedges to tighten.

I'm not familiar with your brands, but if it's a good quality polyurethane construction adhesive, once cured, it should stay put.

When in doubt, leave it clamped longer. When not in doubt, leave it clamped longer anyway. An extra day or two of stepping over clamps is not nearly as inconvenient as trying to do it over...

Comment: I like that "When in doubt, leave it....". That could apply to a whole range of things.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to 2 small dots of sticks like adhesive every 200 to 250mm keeping it down from the top to avoid it sticking out above the skirting. if the wall is bent just wedge it off the other wall. once the adhesive has dried you would pull the wall apart if you tried to get it off.